# `on_typing` event not working on self bot discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

First, I am pretty sure my question is not a duplicate due to differences caused by self bot, and that I can have it working overall.

Basically, I need to get the `on_typing` event as a self bot, however it simply never triggers.

Here is a simple example:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot("example_prefix")

@bot.event
async def on_typing(channel, user, when):
    print("TYPING TRIGGERED")
    print(channel.name)
    print(user.name)

bot.run("TOKEN", bot=False)
```

The behavior is that it never gets triggered.

#### What I have tried

I tried testing if this is some other issue by testing this on a non-self bot, on_typing triggered (after giving intents).

Trying to send intents for typing even as self-bot.

Forcibly dropping intents as self bot (this fixes the recently emerged message events being empty for self bots issue)

And no, don't post a useless answer saying self bots are against TOS and to not use them.

EDIT:

solved, look at answer

DUPLICATE:
And to those saying this is a duplicate of the message content and embed issue, IT IS NOT. This is a different issue and the solution to that doesn't work for this

Comment: If self bots are against TOS we're not going to help you either.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński No, it does not because that is a separate issue that is solved. The fix of basically forcibly dropping intents before sending them and replacing a few recipients and relationships users works for that issue, however doesn't for this issue.


And I severely doubt "You also won't get any help here"  as that other question is a clear example of how people here do care about that use case and it even has quite a lot of points. And I don't think that a question about functionality that is against a service's terms of service is invalid. "won't work ever" too.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński, other libraries such as discord.js and self-bot only libraries do support self-bots. It's just discord.py that doesn't.

Comment: @Ceres discord.py still kinda does, only removed it in the unreleased next version 2.0, current version still works, and there are quite a few attempts/forks to keep it supported

Comment: @Karibiusk, If you're trying to use discord.py>1.4.2 for self bots (after intents were released), the bot simply wont work properly, discord stopped properly responding to any user that sends intents after April 30th and that's why you see the *soft ban* for discord.py, if you're using an older version, it might work or simply use a fork

Comment: They support, but they don’t work @Ceres. discord banned them from the API with some changes (linked on my previous comment)

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution that seems to work.

You need to send this opcode 14 payload to all guilds before on_ready fires for it to work on self bots.

It can work with a patch to discord.py like this

```
From b271d0bdd7cb69b81e13f66e1c2bd74921ed194b Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: Example User <user@example.tld>
Date: Tue, 1 Jun 2021 22:01:27 +0300
Subject: [PATCH] fix on_typing for self bots

To fix on_typing for self code it is needed to send opcode 14 to all
guilds with the required parameters. This also magically fixes the
`on_typing` to work.
---
 discord/client.py | 21 +++++++++++++++++++++
 1 file changed, 21 insertions(+)

diff --git a/discord/client.py b/discord/client.py
index 1c35fddf..ef26a3c5 100644
--- a/discord/client.py
+++ b/discord/client.py
@@ -269,6 +269,27 @@ class Client:
         await self.ws.request_sync(guilds)
 
     def _handle_ready(self):
+        for guild in self.guilds:
+            payload = {
+                "op": 14,
+                "d": {
+                    "guild_id": str(guild.id),
+                    "typing": True,
+                    "threads": False,
+                    "activities": True,
+                    "members": [],
+                    "channels": {
+                        str(guild.channels[0].id): [
+                            [
+                                0,
+                                99
+                            ]
+                        ]
+                    }
+                }
+            }
+
+            asyncio.ensure_future(self.ws.send_as_json(payload), loop=self.loop)
         self._ready.set()
 
     @property
-- 
2.30.2
```